# How to deploy a dymanic web project of java in eclipse to jenkins with less changes in code

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, git-svn

I am new to jenkins so i don't know in depth about it. But in recent days we wanted to change from svn repository to GIT in which we have a java project created in dynamic web project. Now we have to deploy this project in jenkins. But i read that in jenkins only projects created in maven are accepted but not any other. Our project is a huge project and its created using dynamic web project. So if we want to convert to maven project will there be any code changes like many??
What are the jar files or any configuration files needed for the change??

I don't know whether this question is quite suitable to ask or not but we have less time and i am completely new to jenkins.Any suggestions or answers will be valuable to me

Comment: When you say 'dynamic web project' do you mean a project in eclipse?  Are you packaging the application as a .war file or is the application yet to be shipped to production?

Comment: @GrantLay  Yes project in Eclipse. Yet to be shipped to production

Comment: Hi, that is not a true about supporting only java maven, check the [Jenkins plugins page](https://plugins.jenkins.io) or go to administration, modules management and check available plugins over there, there is a lot of supported types of projects :)
You can also install execute shell plugin, then you can make a checkout and just depends on the machine what you have installed- eg. for node projects you can do npm install , etc..

Answer (score 2):

You will need to think about how you will run your application in production.  Will you run it as a packaged war file in tomcat, jetty or another JEE server or will you run it using an embedded server (embedded tomcat etc) where the server is packaged with your application as an executable jar file.

Once you work that out you should think about how you are going to build the application, Maven, Gradle and Ant + Ivy are your three main options.  Jenkins supports all of these options, not just maven.  Besides being able to help you build your application in a standardized way, these tools will be able to help you manage your dependencies.

There really is not much configuration required once you know how to use the tools and your dependencies can be removed from your /lib  folder (or wherever you are currently storing them) as a result.

So take some time to read up about each one, make your choice and then apply it to your project. It is a worthwhile investment and something you will use over an over again.

Comment: We are using Oracle weblogic server and will run as a packaged war file

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins makes a LOT of things easier if you have a Maven project, but you can specify a free form project where you can specify your own build command.   This is not coupled with the git/svn repository.

Experiment with Jenkins.  It is rather nice, and can do a lot of things when you learn it better.